# Unable to download application "<app name> could not be openend at this time" show in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, titanium

I did a ios app using titanium accelerator it is showing

> Unable to download application " could not be openend at this time"

Message time of installing app in iPhone 5 and iPhone 4s and also in latest iPad but It work fine in iPhone 3. I checked some answer in stackoverflow but i am not finding exact solution .

Comment: have u added the all udids and which titanium sdk they were built?

Comment: I added all udid and titanium sdk is 2.3.1